# Connect mySQL database with android

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm new to android .and I'm unable  to connect a phpmyadmin  database  hosted on my pc with  android . 
What are the very basic steps to connect to database with android as i'm unable to  understand it even though there a n number of tutorials on the web.

Comment: Do you mean sqlite database?

Comment: @KristyWelsh  database hosted on my pc with xampp  - phpmyadmin

Comment: There are lots of examples https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TEP3U_aiN-XV8gfW8YDQAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=android+connect+with+php+mysql

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen many tutorials and was unable to understand, let me give a brief introduction and a link to a tutorial which best explains the scenario with screen shots.

To make your android device interact with a remote database (MySQL in your case), you need to write a **webservice** which will get the data from your mysql database and send it to your android app.

**First** of all you need a server (Ex: Wamp). WAMP is acronym for Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP, Perl, Python. WAMP software is one click installer which creates an environment for developing PHP, MySQL web application. By installing this software you will be installing Apache, MySQL and PHP

**Second** Write a php script (webservice) on your server which can retrieve the required data from the MySQL database. This script then encodes the retrieved data inside a JSON object and send it back to your app.

**How it functions?** 
When the android invokes the URL of the webservice (via an HTTP request), the PHP script you wrote is invoked, which does the operations you defined in it and sends back the results you require to the android app. Once the JSON is received at the android app, you have to extract the data in it and use it the way you want.

I hope the explanation above would have given you some idea. If still you got any problems, comment below.

This tutorial excellently illustrates what you are looking for. Hope it helps. URL: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Thanks!